# What server/back-end resources should I use for a Mobile App (Android and IOS) and a Website?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-website

I'm developing an App in IOS with Swift and I don't know which back-end server use, the problem is that I will continue with the website that interacts with the server like the App does. 
I know HTML, CSS, Javascript and Swift. 
What else I must learn to achieve my objective?

Answer (score -1):

***REST API*** 
learn restful architecture first.

And then there are several backend technologies you can use and most of them are open-source technologies :

- nodejs, express.
- django (python framework)
- rails (ruby framework) (rapid app development)

And I think you should really have a look at [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs)

Google's firebase platform offer you **real time database** , authentication, push notifications, analytics, cloud storage, cloud functions(for your backend logic), and hosting.